# Different Platform Support using Makefile

Tags: makefile, preprocessor

I have a application running on both Linux & Mac.
Now, for this application I need to copy some libraries from different path.

For Linux,
cp ../gccRelease/libMsSipRelease.a ../../VoipAppLinux/lib/

For Mac,
cp ../DerivedData/MsSipLib/Build/Products/Debug/libMsSipLib.dylib ../../VoipAppLinux/lib/

As you can see both paths are different.
Now, my question is can I use #ifdef Linux or #ifdef **APPLE** in make file. If can what is the syntax please?
If #ifdef is not possible to use in makefile than how can I solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ifdef APPLE`, but there's a more automatic way: in a makefile, a command like `$(shell uname -s)` will tell Make what the OS is. Try this:

```
OS := $(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
MSSIPLIB := ../gccRelease/libMsSipRelease.a
else
MSSIPLIB := ../DerivedData/MsSipLib/Build/Products/Debug/libMsSipLib.dylib
endif

# And later on
cp $(MSSIPLIB) ../../VoipAppLinux/lib/
```